# Spring @Transactional based on condition at method level

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have a method which has a configurable transaction behaviour, like based on a boolean value it should apply `@Transactional` on that method. Is there something like this:

```
@Transactional(if myBooleanVariable is true)
public boolean executeQueries(List<String> queries) {
    Iterator<String> it = queries.iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the injecting beans conditionally are possible. There are lots of ways, however, I recommend you to use profiles.

It allows you to have more unnamed beans of the same time based on the profile.

```
@Bean
@Profile("!dev")
public class MyClass1 implements MyInterface {}

@Bean
@Profile("dev")
public class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {}
```

You can configure the profile using in the Java Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
    }
}
```

Then the annotation `@Autowired` will find the proper implementation to inject based on the active profile. Read more on the [Baeldung's websize](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles), where I took the example from.

---

The second way is to use the annotation [@Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html), which injects the bean conditionally based on the return method of the implemented interface [Condition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html).

```
@Bean
@Conditional(MyClass1Condition.class)
public class MyClass1 implements MyInterface {}

@Bean
@Conditional(MyClass2Condition.class)
public class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {}
```

Here is how the implementation skeleton would look like:

```
public class MyClass1Condition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        // perform your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i do something at method level?